# need good resources about {on the fly encryption or Real-time encryption}

Tags: encryption, real-time

I need to Know about on fly encryption or Real-time encryption because I am trying to implement real time encryption which is some thing smiler to  truecrypt (just the idea of the real-time encryption technique)

so where can i find a good resource talking about solid concepts in the field of this topic.

I have experience using public key encryption and also symmetric key encryption.

Comment: I remember my Cryptography teacher telling us never to use our onwn code for production if the algorithm is already available and used. I agree with him, you never know if their is a flaw until someone exploit it (remember debian openSSL). Well if you are making research in the cryptography field that s probably different.